Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Is there a conflict between Mindfulness-based and Acceptance-based Therapies and Cognitive Behaviour Therapy (CBT)?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)  
What are the dangers of using mindfulness-based techniques for individuals suffering from Schizophrenia?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)  
Good conferences on (computational) neuroscience in Europe and whether to submit to conference or journal?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)  
What is actually going on in your brain during a night terror?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)  
The psychology of patriotism, dying for one's own country
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)  
What is the difference between implicit and explicit attitudes?
Net Score: -4 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 4)  
How to design ballot papers with a large number of candidates in a preferential system?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Dreams and sleep phases, and duration of dreams
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)  
How does the personality of a successful leader influence the development of his children?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Differences between anger and rage
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)  

